# Ubuntu / GParted can find HDD, installs fine, but no HDD found after install/reboot

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I'm not sure if this is an Ubuntu issue or a hardware one, but I'm trying to install 16.04 on an old Optiplex 990 with a new 4TB HDD.

From USB, GParted can find the HDD, and the installer sets up Ubuntu fine. The HDD also shows up in the BIOS. But on boot, post-install, I keep getting "No Hard Drive Found." I've tried moving the drive from SATA0 to SATA1 -- still detected in the BIOS and GParted -- but still "No Hard Drive Found" on boot.

Any ideas on what's going on here -- why I can see the HDD in BIOS, and with GParted and through the install process, but the HDD can't be found as a bootable drive afterwards?

Comment: 1. Change SATA type from RAID to AHCI 2. If you mean 4TB, BIOS only supports 2TB so you need to be cautious.

Comment: If BIOS sees drive correctly (as 4TB) and you have it partitioned with gpt, not MBR, do you have an ESP for UEFI boot or a bios_grub for BIOS boot? Grub will not correctly install otherwise. And those partitions need to be near beginning of drive. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu Use ppa version with your live installer,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please attach link to the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Yes, TB — edited original. Maybe I’m naive but I assumed that the installation process would create all the necessary partitions, etc. — I'll run through the above instructions, and thank you!